# SSIS - passing an object variable in an expression of a task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

In my SSIS package (on Sql 2008 R2), I have a TransferObjectsTask task, and this task has a property called DatabaseDetails, which is of DatabaseInfoCollection type. What I am looking to do is specify a value for this property by preparing it in a script task prior and saving it in a variable of object type, and then passing this variable to the TransferObjectsTask task's DatabaseDetails property. Simple enough, right?

BUT, as you may have already guessed, I cannot do this. When I specify the variable in the expression, I get...

**"Expression cannot be evaluated / The data type of variable  is not supported in an expression."**

How can I get around this?

There is literally nothing to "evaluate" as the expression just has a variable name. Why would a task expose a property in expression if you cannot even specify a variable for it? Doesn't make sense.

What am I missing??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference an object in an expression. The object data type is too generic. You can literally push just about anything into an object data type. Imagine pushing a list of 100 databases into an object variable (making it an array), then passing that variable to the InitialCatalog property of an oledb connection manager. Not only would the connection manager not know what to do with the object, but even if it did, it couldn't connect to 100 databases at once.

What exactly are you trying to do? I'm not familiar with the TransferObjectsTask (and have been doing significant SSIS work since the product came out). Is this a custom task? It's not included in the control flow tasks for SQL 2012. There is a Transfer SQL Server Objects task. Is that what you're referring to? If so, Powershell or a 3rd party tool like Red Gate's SQL Compare would be a much better option. SSIS is very good at ETL (extracting, transforming in the buffer, and loading millions/billions of records from/to various sources & destinations). It's a bit kludgy at administrative tasks though. I would never use it for simple administrative tasks like backups, schema update deployments, or index maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to perform a database copy operation. I started with the Database Copy wizard in Sql Mgmt Studio and then exported the auto-generated package to a DTSX file. The TransferObjectsTask task ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.TransferObjectsTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"), and only this, is what I found sitting in the DTSX file. Not sure if it is the same as "Transfer SQL Server Objects".

Comment: I understand your explanation, but in your example wouldn't the type of InitialCatalog property tell you exactly the kind of object it is? And hence wouldn't you treat any value passed to it to be of that type and try to work with it? At least that is my thinking. Nevermind about evaluating it as an expression. For now, I am sticking with SSIS since I have some familiarity with it.

Comment: I'd suggest working with objects in code to understand the issue. Create and populate an object in one script task and pass it to a variable. In another script task, read the variable in and deconstruct it. If you manage to do this, you'll understand objects much better.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldnt make sense to add an object to an expression. How would you know the structure of the object.

Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do? The [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx)
simply transfer an object from a source to a destination. What are you trying to set on "DatabaseDetails" (I cant couldn't find this property)

Comment: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.TransferObjectsTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91". I am trying to copy a database. I was hoping it would assume the object to be the same type as the property to which it is being assigned.